# "Ambiguos use of function" when overloading a generic function in Swift

Tags: swift, generics, overloading

Below you'll see a playground where I try to illustrate my problem. I have a class (`Foo`) with some overloaded generic methods (`bar<T>()`) whose return types depends on the generic parameter. I have 3 methods:

- One must return a subclass of a specific type (in the example below it is called `BaseClass`)
- Other one must return a `Array` of instances of this specific type.
- The last should be used as default one if the other two conditions are not fulfilled.

The problem comes when I call the method. Even if I tell the compiler what is the type I am expecting, it gives me the error **Ambiguos use of bar()**.

```
import UIKit

class BaseClass {
    required init() {}
}

class Foo {

    // 1
    func bar<T: BaseClass>() -> T? {
        // Just a default implementation, it should do real work inside
        return T()
    }

    // 2
    func bar<T: BaseClass>() -> [T]? {
        // Just a default implementation, it should do real work inside
        return []
    }

    // 3
    func bar<T>() -> T? {
        // Just a default implementation, it should do real work inside
        return "Test" as? T
    }
}

let foo = Foo()

// Should call "1", because it return type is BaseClass
let baseClassObject: BaseClass? = foo.bar()

// Should call "2", because it return type is [BaseClass]
let baseClasArray: [BaseClass]? = foo.bar()

// Should call "3", because it return type is neither BaseClass nor [BaseClass]
let anyOtherObject: String = foo.bar()
```

In my opinion, the compiler should know what method call, cause I am telling it the return type, right? is this a limitation with generics or am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

**Update 19th April**

In an answer they say that the conflicts comes because "BaseClass" can be interpreted as `BaseClass` but also as `T`. But in this modified playground, the compilers does infers which method use properly. Is there any difference? should I have the same conflict here?:

```
import UIKit

class BaseClass {
    required init() {}
}

class Foo {

    // 1
    func bar<T: BaseClass>(param: T) -> String {
        return "I am BaseClass"
    }

    // 2
    func bar<T: BaseClass>(param: [T]) -> String {
        return "I am [BaseClass]"
    }

    // 3
    func bar<T>(param: T) -> String {
        return "I am other thing"
    } 
}

let foo = Foo()

// It prints "I am BaseClass"
foo.bar(BaseClass())

// It prints "I am [BaseClass]"
foo.bar([BaseClass(), BaseClass()])

// It prints "I am another thing"
foo.bar(NSObject())
```

Answer (score 2):

Number 3 causes conflict with the other functions

This is because < T > could also be of type BaseClass and of type [BaseClass]. The compiler simply sees an interface of "throw anything in here" which will conflict with any more specific level of specificity.

Comment: To expand on this, why should `let baseClassObject: BaseClass? = foo.bar()` automatically call the first `bar`?

Comment: Yes, I know the conflict comes from the last one. I think the compiler knows that I am calling the first one because of the return type. I thought the compiler checks from more specific to less specific and use the more specific one. At least, it does this way in other cases. Please, @PEEJWEEJ, see my question update.